# Yii Widgets CGridView show data

Tags: yii, widget, where-clause, cgridview, dataprovider

I have 2 tables in my DB: **t_product** and **t_user**.

**t_user**

'***************************************************************************'

'* cod_arm * descrição        * **username** * password * salt   * tipo *'

'***************************************************************************'

'*    000  * 000 - ADMIN      * admin    * 123      * asdfgh *   A  *'

'*    001  * 001 - MEDICINA 1 * **P01**      * 123      * asdf   *   U  *'

'*    021  * 021 - UROLOGIA   * P21      * 123      * asdfg  *   U  *'

****************************************************************************'

**t_product**

'*********************************************************************************************'

'* id_prod * cod_art       * designacao * unidade * data_validade   * **cod_loc** *'

'*********************************************************************************************'

'*    1  * 210110300 * ADESIVO COMUM (...)    * ROL      * 2014-11-30 *   **P010101**  *'

'*    2  * 210110320 * ADESIVO COMUM (...)    * ROL      * NULL *   **P01**  *'

'*    3  * 210110302 * ADESIVO COMUM (...)    * ROL      * 2016-12-30 *   *P210110*  *'

'*    4  * 210110301 * ADESIVO COMUM (...)    * ROL      * 2014-11-30 *   **P010101**  *'

'*    1  * 210110300 * ADESIVO COMUM (...)    * ROL      * 2014-11-30 *   **P01EXT**  *'

'*    1  * 210110300 * ADESIVO COMUM (...)    * ROL      * 2014-11-30 *   *P210101*  *'

'***********************************************************************************************'

I want, when user click in "Manage Product". Table show all products **where cod_loc like 'username%'**.

exemp: In this case the user is "P01". In this page-"Manage Produtos" I want show all products where cod_loc beginning with "P01".

I try whith dataProvider. In model->Product .. But i cannot show what i want! I can show all products where cod_loc are exactly match with username (ex."P01") and I can show all products where cod_loc have "P","0" and "1", and this case are almost all produts.

---

Well, in my model Product i have that code:

```html
<?php

/**
 * This is the model class for table "produto".
 *
 * The followings are the available columns in table 'produto':
 * @property integer $idProduto
 * @property integer $cod_art
 * @property string $designacao
 * @property string $unidades
 * @property string $data_validade
 * @property string $cod_loc
 * @property string $username
 *
 * The followings are the available model relations:
 * @property User $username0
 */
class Produto extends CActiveRecord
{
 /**
  * @return string the associated database table name
  */
 public function tableName()
 {
  return 'produto';
 }

 /**
  * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
  */
 public function rules()
 {
  // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
  // will receive user inputs.
  return array(
   array('cod_art, designacao, unidades, cod_loc', 'required'),
   array('cod_art', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
   array('designacao', 'length', 'max'=>128),
   array('unidades', 'length', 'max'=>6),
   array('cod_loc', 'length', 'max'=>12),
   array('username', 'length', 'max'=>3),
   array('data_validade', 'safe'),
   // The following rule is used by search().
   // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
   array('idProduto, cod_art, designacao, unidades, data_validade, cod_loc, username', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
  );
 }

 /**
  * @return array relational rules.
  */
 public function relations()
 {
  // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
  // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
  return array(
   'username0' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'username'),
  );
 }

 /**
  * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
  */
 public function attributeLabels()
 {
  return array(
   //'idProduto' => 'Id Produto',
   'cod_art' => 'Cod Art',
   'designacao' => 'Designacao',
   'unidades' => 'Unidades',
   'data_validade' => 'Data Validade',
   'cod_loc' => 'Cod Loc',
   //'username' => 'Username',
  );
 }

 /**
  * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
  *
  * Typical usecase:
  * - Initialize the model fields with values from filter form.
  * - Execute this method to get CActiveDataProvider instance which will filter
  * models according to data in model fields.
  * - Pass data provider to CGridView, CListView or any similar widget.
  *
  * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models
  * based on the search/filter conditions.
  */
 public function search()
 {
  // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

  //$criteria=new CDbCriteria;

  /*$criteria->compare('cod_arm',$this->cod_arm);
  $criteria->compare('descricao',$this->descricao,true);
  $criteria->compare('username',$this->username,true);
  $criteria->compare('password',$this->password,true);
  $criteria->compare('salt',$this->salt,true);
  $criteria->compare('tipo',$this->tipo,true);*/
                $username = Yii::app()->user->name;
  return new CActiveDataProvider('Produto', array(
                    'criteria'=>array(
                    'condition'=>'cod_loc LIKE :username%',
                    'params' => array(
                        ':username'=>$username
                    )
                ),
            ));
 }

 /**
  * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
  * Please note that you should have this exact method in all your CActiveRecord descendants!
  * @param string $className active record class name.
  * @return Produto the static model class
  */
 public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
 {
  return parent::model($className);
 }
}
```

---

And in my views>Produto>admin.php I have this code:

```html
<?php
/* @var $this ProdutoController */
/* @var $model Produto */

$this->breadcrumbs=array(
 'Produtos'=>array('index'),
 'Manage',
);

$this->menu=array(
 array('label'=>'List Produto', 'url'=>array('index')),
 array('label'=>'Create Produto', 'url'=>array('create')),
);

Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('search', "
$('.search-button').click(function(){
 $('.search-form').toggle();
 return false;
});
$('.search-form form').submit(function(){
 $('#produto-grid').yiiGridView('update', {
  data: $(this).serialize()
 });
 return false;
});
");
?>

<h1>Manage Produtos</h1>

<p>
You may optionally enter a comparison operator (<b>&lt;</b>, <b>&lt;=</b>, <b>&gt;</b>, <b>&gt;=</b>, <b>&lt;&gt;</b>
or <b>=</b>) at the beginning of each of your search values to specify how the comparison should be done.
</p>

<?php echo CHtml::link('Advanced Search','#',array('class'=>'search-button')); ?>
<div class="search-form" style="display:none">
<?php $this->renderPartial('_search',array(
 'model'=>$model,
)); ?>
</div><!-- search-form -->
<?php echo $AP = Yii::app()->User->name; ?>
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
 'id'=>'produto-grid',
 'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
 'filter'=>$model,
 'columns'=>array(
  //'idProduto',
  'cod_art',
  'designacao',
  'unidades',
  'data_validade',
  'cod_loc',
  /*
  'username',
  */
  array(
   'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
  ),
 ),
)); ?>
```

In mysql, i can do what i want -> SELECT * FROM produto WHERE cod_loc LIKE 'username%';

Comment: Please include the relevant source code where you are trying your aproach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not going deeply in your code an answer may be in this code example:

```
$username = 'P01' ;
Product::model()->findAll('cod_loc LIKE :username', array(
    ':username'=>"{$username}%"
));
```

or in data provider:

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Product', array(
    'criteria'=>array(
        'condition'=>'cod_loc LIKE :username',
        'params' => array(
            ':username'=>"{$username}%"
        )
    ),
));
```

By `Product` I mean the model class for `t_product` table.

Comment: Sorry, but i am newbie.. i edit my question.. if you can help me

Comment: i edit my question.. and i include relevant source code, i think.. thanks! @MauricioGracia

Comment: now i have this CDbexception:
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 Erreur de syntaxe près de '%' à la ligne 1. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `produto` `t` WHERE cod_loc LIKE :username%

Comment: I corrected my code by moving wildcard `%` from condition to param bounding. Try now. This is just a possible solution for you and my code is not tested in real application.